# Google Analytics trackevent in single-page web app

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application, data-analysis, pageviews

What is the best (most practical) way to use Google Analytics trackevent for tracking "pageviews" in a single-page web app? trackevent takes four arguments: CATEGORY, ACTION, LABEL, VALUE. The last two are optional. Which field should I use for the view title? A "view" in a single-page web app corresponds to a page in a normal web app.

I can see two options:

```
1) trackevent('Navigation', 'View title');
2) trackevent('Navigation', 'Click', '', 'View title'); 
trackevent('Navigation', 'Redirect', '', 'View title');
```

Of course one *can* do either, but which option is best when it comes to analyzing the data in Google Analytics?

Comment: I found the answers in this excellent article: [The Complete Google Analytics Event Tracking Guide Plus 10 Amazing Examples](http://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/the-complete-google-analytics-event-tracking-guide-plus-10-amazing-examples/):

Comment: Have you considered just pushing trackPageviews of virtual pages? Like modeling your application as if it had different pages (which, in effect, it does)

Comment: I have considered it, but decided to go for events because 1) I would like to separate pageview-by-click from pageview-by-redirect and 2) I track quite a few other events in the app, so I thought it would be simpler to have it all as events. What are the advantages of using trackPageview instead?

Answer (score 9):

The [Angulartics](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/) plugin provides web analytics for AngularJS applications. There is an [example application](http://angulartics.herokuapp.com/google-analytics.html#/) which uses Google Analytics.

It supports:

- page tracking
- event tracking
- scroll tracking

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking for a specific plugins for your routing framework. I am using knockout for MVVM and [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) for routing purpose. I found it as an excellent tool for routing and based on my understanding it is under active development/maintenance.

Sammy developer created a [pluging](https://github.com/britg/sammy-google-analytics) for interracting with google analytics which handles all the work for you. It is pretty easy to use:

```
$.sammy(function() { with(this) {
  use(Sammy.GoogleAnalytics)

  ...
}});
```

Comment: That's nice if you're using sammy.js, but not everyone is.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde this is exactly why I wrote that this works for sammy.js. Have not seen the same comment from you below angular answer.